# How to execute Keras.Net with VSIX extension, C#

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, keras, vsix

I am trying to load a **Keras** model from a **button click** on **WinForm (img-1)** and winform is loaded by clicking a **Menu Button**. But when I click on that button, I'm getting an **exception (img-2)**.

**img-1**
[image: WinForm]

**img-2**
[image: exception]

**img-3**

[image: btn]

Following is the code of my loading a model:

```
private void Button_click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var path = @"E:\Tanmay-data\ML\ML.Net Test\myApp\";
            var modelpath = path + "issue_classifier_w2vec_new.h5";
            new LoadModel(modelpath);
        }
```

```
namespace MLExtTest2
{
    class LoadModel
    {
        public LoadModel(string modelpath)
        {
            var model = Keras.Models.Model.LoadModel(modelpath);
            MessageBox.Show(model.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

But, When I execute the same code in a **console application**, not in a VSIX application, It executes perfectly and .h5 model also gets loaded successfully.

For loading **Keras** model, I installed **Keras.Net** from **NuGet** in **Package Manager Console** of visual studio 2019.
I also installed **tensorflowsharp and tensorflow** in background in package manager console.

I think the problem is, These libraries are not being loaded when VSIX Experimental Window is loading. Or ML model can only be loaded with a console app?

Please help me out how to load keras model in vsix project. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by a VSIX application. a .VSIX file is nothing more than a .zip file that installs and registers a Visual Studio extension. How exactly is this winform invoked? VS extensions typically use winform controls in toolwindows and designers. Can you provide more context here?

Comment: You are right @EdDore, I am creating a VSIX Extension (typically a menu button as img-3). This button opens a window form (as in img-1). Inside this window form, on clicking the button 'Test', a .h5 file is being loading (A file which is a machine learning model coded in keras). But when I click on this, It is showing an exception (as in img-3). When I run the same code in a console application (through vs 2019 IDE) it runs fine. but in vsix project which is an extension project, it doesn't work.

Comment: Tanmay, how "exactly" are you invoking/displaying this winform? Is it running withing the devenv.exe process itself? devenv.exe is a 32bit specific process. Do these other components like Keras.NET tensorflowsharp, etc all support x86 code generation?

Comment: this winform is invoking because "I am exactly working on a project which is a visual studio 2019 plugin that is selecting a specific directory from a tree view window UI (which is a winform) then a button click event is supposed to load that ML model" @EdDore